# How to log plugin errors to plugin error_log file

Tags: plugin-development, customization, errors

How can errors, specific to a given plugin, be logged to an `error_log` file contained within the plugin root folder itself?

**Examples:**

- Syntax errors
- Database errors
- Compatibility errors
- PHP fatal errors
- Ajax request errors

Similar to the `/wp-content/debug.log` file enable when `WP_DEBUG_LOG` is defined as `true` in the `wp-config.php` file (*albeit specifically for plugins with its concerns separated from any other general error unrelated to the plugin itself*).

**Research:**

**[Debugging Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress#Debugging_Plugins)** section in the official documentation of the Codex refers to using 3<sup>rd</sup> party plugins to debug 3<sup>rd</sup> party plugins.

**[Don’t Develop Without Debugging](https://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/ten-things-every-wordpress-plugin-developer-should-know/#don-t-develop-without-debugging)**<sup>by Smashing Magazine</sup> refers to site-wide general debugging.

**[Plugin Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/best-practices/)** appears to layout no specific guidelines.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By setting the second argument to 3 for `error_log`:

```
$pluginlog = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'debug.log';
$message = 'SOME ERROR'.PHP_EOL;
error_log($message, 3, $pluginlog);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Comment: I can't be as responsive as I'd like to be, but I'll explore this solution and revert with feedback when possible.

Comment: By all indications, and upon further reading on the provided source documentation, this appears to be the correct answer for the scope defined in the problem statement. Error handling is typically more verbose, but that would be off-topic for the issue described here, and I believe this will work well with exception handling using `try()` and `catch()` blocks (I'll be exploring this route next...).

Comment: yes I figured since you mentioned so many different types of errors you were looking for something as generic as this so you can test and log any message where needed. Apart from exceptions as you mention, the PHP fatal errors would require some extra handling via `register_shutdown_function` or using the shutdown hook, eg. `add_action('shutdown', 'custom_catch_fatals');`

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this, I'll explore these methods as well.

Comment: I used some of this stuff in a project recently so you may find it useful for reference: https://gist.github.com/majick777/6c4e4074ce4a59fe09f7baa855732aee

Comment: Great, this should help put things into context. Much appreciated!