# How to debug user_register hook

Tags: hooks

I created this selectbox inside my user-edit.php screen trough edit_user_profile hook.

```
<table class="form-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="select_membership">Plano de Membros</label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <select id="select_membership" name="select_membership"><option id="0">Sem plano</option>
                    <option value="1">Plano 1</option>
                    <option value="2" selected="selected">Plano 2</option>
                    <option value="3">Plano 3</option>
                    <option value="4">Plano 4</option>
                    <option value="5">Plano 5</option>
                    <option value="6">Plano 6</option>
                    <option value="7">Plano 7</option>
                </select>
            </td>       
        </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now I'm trying to get the selectbox value inside the user_register hook with  this function:

```
public function update_membership_field( $user_id ){
        $membership_methods = new IMS_Membership_Method();
        $membership_methods->update_user_membership($user_id, $_POST['select_membership']);
    }
```

But nothing happens. How I can know if some data is passing through this function to check if something is happening? How to debug? I can't print nothing using this function.

Comment: Rafael, 'user_register' fires when  a user registers, not when a user is edited or updated.   Please also show the add_action code and when that is being added in case the problem lies there.  Try something like https://codex.wordpress.org/edit_user_profile_update

Comment: Hi anmari, thanks for your answer. It was the wrong hook i'm using...I change to edit_user_profile_update and know I can update my db with my methods. Thanks! Just to understand 100% this hook can not print anything? like echo "test";?

Comment: Hi Rafael, re output in hooks.  It depends when/how the hook is being executed.  The user profile ones are tricky because wp does stuff to prevent a double submission. One could use error_log to output where one can read it. More detail here:      https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131212/debug-output-during-filter-execution-doesnt-work?rq=1

Comment: This might also help to understand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878279/how-to-debug-save-post-actions-in-wordpress  and for plugin specifc logging https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291108/how-to-log-plugin-errors-to-plugin-error-log-file

Comment: Hi Anmari, you helped me a lot! Now I can debug this function...I understand the idea through your links and now I'm redirecting the values to an email :) thanks!

Comment: Anmari, considering make your comments an answer...I think this way I can properly mark what you said a solved answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rafael, (as requested, turning comments into answer)

'user_register' fires when a user registers, not when a user is edited or updated. Try something like https://codex.wordpress.org/edit_user_profile_update

Wrt output in hooks. It depends when/how the hook is being executed. The user profile ones are tricky because wp does stuff to prevent a double submission. One could use error_log to output where one can read it. More detail here: [Debug output during filter execution doesn't work](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131212/)…

This might also help to understand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878279/… and for plugin specifc logging [How to log plugin errors to plugin error_log file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291108/)